# Preload images/sound to avoid lag

Tags: iphone, audio, uiimageview

Im developing a game where I have a player that shoots objects. When the player shoots a sound is played. And when he hits an object it generates a explosion animation as well as a sound. Im using UIImageViews to draw the player and the object and I use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound to play the sounds.

The problem that I'm experiencing is that the game "lags" the first time i Shoot and the first time I hit an object. I think it is because these objects are not yet loaded in to memory because it's only the first time that these objects are generated that the problems occur. After the first time the game doesn't suffer from lag.

Is there a way to preload these objects in to memory so that the game doesn't lag each time a new object is generated for the first time?

Answer (score 2):

Just place the creation of your `UIImage` instances and your calls of `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()` in a method that runs before the gameplay actually starts. As long as your resources are small enough to fit into memory, that should do it.

You should listen to memory warnings, though, and release all objects that are not currently in use to free as much memory as possible. The user probably prefers a slight lag when reloading these objects over your app crashing because it ran out of memory.

Comment: Worked for me for AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(), but since since you don't keep any pointers to it, do they get autoreleased if there is memory problem?